# mysql gem installation failure in ruby on rails on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tried several things like archflags, mysql-config directory settings and everything. I am getting the following error for script/server when I am using mysql as database. For other databases its working fine. I am using ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.5 and gems 1.3.6 and mysql-2.7 gem. Can you please help me to solve this. The error output is as follows:

```
!!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Mon Jul 18 13:07:24 -0700 2011
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7/lib/mysql.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7/lib/mysql.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7/lib/mysql.bundle
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7/lib/mysql.bundle
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/requires.rb:7:in `require_library_or_gem'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/requires.rb:5:in `require_library_or_gem'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:61:in `mysql_connection'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `send'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `checkout'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `loop'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `checkout'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:93:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/chunked.rb:15:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:64:in `process'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:34:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:111
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    script/server:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Mysql. [Here is the correct list.](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php?p=mysql-5.1&v=5.1.37)

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```